# Send Mail : what is difference between host smtp.gmail.com vs smtp.domainname.com? Which configuration is better/fast?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter for my project & I want to send bulk email to guest. I did below 2 mailing configuration & both are working but I am not able to find the better/fast.

**Which configuration is fast/better & reduce spam mail? 
is smtp.domain.com take more time to send mail possibility?
is there any mailing limit different for both?**

**1) Using gmail.com (G suite):**

```
Protocal : "SMTP"
Host : "smtp.gmail.com"
Port : "465"
user : 'xyz@domainname.com'
pass : '123456'
```

**2) Using domainname.com (hosting provider, limit per hr = 500):**

```
Protocal : "SMTP"
Host : "smtp.domainname.com"
Port : "587"
user : 'noreply@domainname.com'
pass : '123456'
```

Comment: what do you mean "reduce spam mail"? as i see it you are the one sending mail in bulk. if you want the *best* (morally sound) option, imo use a reputable service like mail chimp and have everyone who wants to receive mail, newsletters, promos, .etc. subscribe.

Comment: @alex some times mail will go into spam.. is this issue creates bcz of the configuration?... Just i wanted to know which one is better configuration from above two configurations?

Comment: again, you are the one sending mail, correct? so you are saying your mail is going in to spam on the receivers end? you are sending mail in bulk, where are you getting the emails from? did they subscribe to get emails from you? does your email content contain "spamy" content that are caught by spam filters? is your email address/domain you are sending from "blacklisted" because of numerous spam reports? there are too many variables. https://optinmonster.com/11-reasons-why-your-emails-go-in-the-spam-box-and-how-to-make-sure-they-dont/

Comment: every 2hr my cron job execute one script & sending mail to guest which are registered on our portal... I just wanted to know which service is better than above... I found one issue that when i send mail using 'smtp.domainname.com' then the process is slow.. Is this bcz of  smtp.domainname.com? 'spam mail is another point'... just want which one is better configuration? why?

Comment: i would use google, but that's just because that is what I use and found to be more reliable  (i'm not sure there is any hard data on this claim). from experience, if you emails go in the spam folder of your guests email account that is not something you can entirely control. many providers have their own implementations that aren't entirely known. the best you can do is make sure your email address is "trusted" and that your content isn't "spamy"

Comment: @Alex i search so many content but did not get any satisfy answer...  I was also implemented base on what i found but then i realise if 2 services are available then why we are only using single one... is their any way to use both service means suppose one service per day limit is over then use 2nd service.. or wise versa... or alternatively use both services

Comment: does you hosting provider have a limit? also this might be useful: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Comment: Yes.. Limit is per hr = 500... on this link there is no hr limit

Comment: Don't use personal mailer system for applications to send an email. use a mailer system designed for that task.

Answer (score 0):

So for starters what you are doing should not be using a personal email provider system.

As your using an application (php website) to do this mailing you should be using a system such as [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) or [MailGun](https://mailgun.com) (both I think to offer free versions) and use there PHP Libraries you should not really be using a personal email system to send out a mass mail.

**Using personal mail providers**

So here are some of the key points between none specific hosted email (such as a server running CPanel) and dedicated email provider systems this could be Google's Gsuit or Zoho but as you said Gmail I will focus on that so not all of these features are available to all dedicated email provider systems.

**Security**

If you use SSL / TLS as you should be now. to connect to SMTP the Certificate used is for SMTP.gmail.com that Google pays for so you would have to get your own Certificates issues and for the same level of protection and verification could cost quite a bit. But, that is only if your hosting provider allows it. otherwise, your stuck using unencrypted emails that are open to a MITM attack.

The Amount of Servers Google Mail Has and it's unlimited usage, so with what you have said your hosting provider limits you to 500 emails per hour, is that across all your email addresses, so as you get more staff that could become a big problem.

Google SMTP also uses two-factor authentication and for an application to use it you have to generate an application specific password that should your servers be breached you just terminate that password and create a new one it's also good practice to do this every couple of months. but that does not stop the owner logging in via the website that stays the same. so a security breach of the email account is easier to handle.

**Security personal thoughts**

My Self personally would never trust a system that has to use throttling with low amounts it means they are using a limiting feature instead of a security feature to protect them selfs. not a good sign of security.

**Speed**

As for speed that's down the load of the servers, Google has more servers for Gmail than your domain email provider and will be better able to handle the load so would be quicker at times of high load but to how much depends on load the servers are under.

Again on the security side but as a speed measure, yourdomain SMTP provider could be DDOSed and not work that is never going to happen to Google's SMTP Servers.

Comment: 2 hourly(2 hr cron job) I want to sending 300 mails from queue(db table)... G Suite provide 2,000 per day & domain host provide 500 per hr. so using which config i will use?

Comment: Sending that many emails you should be using SendGrid or MailGun I personally use MailGun it's the better API I find. as for you comment do the maths `24x300 = 7,200/2 = 3,100` or `12 * 300 = 3,100` so that stops you using Gmail/G Suit

Comment: my share hosting providing me to send mail 500 per hr... Can i use that configuration?